# table - style display none

Tags: apex, visualforce, table, style, column

I am trying to make a billing invoice with table.
Using style display is great and working well. however, I would like to show whole column if there is at least one row isn't empty. 
so the second row is supposed to show the comment even though I set as

`style="display:{!IF(ISBLANK(item.AcctSeed__Comment__c), 'none', 'row')};" >`

anybody can help me?

[image]

Comment: Can you the share expected output image?

Answer (score 0):

Create output label and use rendered attribute to check condition then close output label. Within outpoutlabel to enter Null, after closing the output label to print text.
'<'apex:outputLabel rendered="{!if(Account.Owner.title=null,true,false)}">Null'<'/apex:outputLabel'>'{!Account.Owner.title}

I have used for the same purpose you mentioned. I hope it will help to you.